# How to fetch images from web site?

Tags: python

- I want to download images from website (for example: https://pixabay.com/)
- I want filler which images to download (for example: 'river' or 'house')

Is there a simple library which I can connect to a web site (for example: https://pixabay.com/) and filter which images to download (and to limit number of images per filter to download) ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions

Comment: You can use beautifulsoup to perform web crawler tasks. It can filter html by tag or attribute but you still need to know how to call the pixabay endpoints. I think Boom meant is there a simple library not "code"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pixabay api for that. You need to take this steps:

1. Create account pixabay.com
2. Go to this page and get `Your API key`
   https://pixabay.com/api/docs/#api_rate_limit
   .

You will be able to make 5,000 requests per hour.

3. Install `pip install python-pixabay`
4. Sample code

`

```
from pixabay import Image, Video

API_KEY = 'x'
image = Image(API_KEY)
image.search()

def download(url, pathname):
    if not os.path.isdir(pathname):
        os.makedirs(pathname)
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    file_size = int(response.headers.get("Content-Length", 0))
    filename = os.path.join(pathname, url.split("/")[-1])
    progress = tqdm(response.iter_content(1024), f"Downloading {filename}", total=file_size, unit="B", unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1024)
    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        for data in progress.iterable:
            f.write(data)
            progress.update(len(data))

ims = image.search(q='cats dogs',lang='es',image_type='photo',orientation='horizontal',category='animals',safesearch='true',order='latest',page=2,per_page=3)

print(ims)
download(ims['hits'][0].get('previewURL'), 'photos')
```